# What is the function get_token_user_sub() supposed to do?

Tags: documentation, authlib

I am currently building an OAuth 2.0 endpoint with authlib.
At the stage of creating a token introspection endpoint, the official documentation suggests a function [`get_token_user_sub(token)`](http://docs.authlib.org/en/stable/specs/rfc7662.html#authlib.oauth2.rfc7662.IntrospectionEndpoint.introspect_token) in the method `introspect_token()`. What is it supposed to return? What is a "sub" in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sub` is `subject` in userinfo, usually it is the user ID.